# How exactly does DNA polymerase III detect a mismatched base?

Tags: genetics, dna-replication, polymerase

How exactly does DNA polymerase III detect a mismatched base? I know how it removes it, via exonuclease activity, but how does it 'detect' it molecularly in the first place?